# Comparing Numeric Fields In Elasticsearch vs. Setting Dedicated Boolean Fields

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm working in a Go application that makes queries to an elasticsearch index (version 7.17). I have a requirement to build a filter/query that compares 2 long fields in that index (A and B) and returns documents where A < B within the same document. I was trying to determine the best way to do this, and a lot of the info I had found while searching pointed me to `script` queries. The script queries are pretty straight forward, but I've read they can be resource intensive.

One idea I had to avoid a script query is adding a boolean field mapping called ~ "a_less_than_b". Our Go code performs some transformations on structs before they're sent to elastic as documents, so it would be trivial for me to set that field based on the corresponding A and B attributes on the Go struct.

Is there some simpler way to implement the comparison on the elasticsearch side instead of a script query, or would setting that dedicated boolean field be a cleaner, more performant solution?

Comment: I will suggest to set boolean field at index time which will be easy to query and perfoemance wise also it is efficient.

Comment: I'm just adding the reference of elastic script queries here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: A bit of code would be welcome here, and reference to concepts you're dealing with would have been a plus. I'm +1 anyway on this question because it's pretty well written and clear. Thank you